# how to use python to merge rows with partially duplicated data

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge two rows which have many repeated data. For example：

df1:

```
name  area  number    major
Amy   Cal   1234       Math
Amy   Cal   1234       English
```

df2:

```
name  area  number    major
Amy   Cal   1234       Math-English
```

I want to know how can I change df1 into df2 with Python. Thanks!

Comment: Use `df = df.groupby(['name','area','number'])['major'].apply('-'.join).reset_index()`

Comment: It works. Thank you so much.